# C++ : How to detect duplicates in vector<string> and print ONE copy?

Tags: c++, duplicates, stdvector

I'm new to C++. I was wondering how I can find duplicate strings in a vector and print out ONE copy of the string. For example, if I had <"cat", "dog", "dog", "bird",> it would print out cat, dog, bird. I have sorted my vector and am using the adjacent_find function and iterating through the vector (since I have to find if any word is duplicated). My code detects duplicates, but it only prints out the non-duplicates. I would like to alter it to print out all the non-duplicates and also just ONE of the duplicates, so all strings in the vector are printed out. Here is the code I have so far:

```
public: void print(vector<string> in) // print method for printing a vector and it's key
{ 

  sort(in.begin(), in.end()); // sort the vector alphabetically first

  vector<string>::iterator it; 

      for( it = in.begin(); it != in.end(); it++ ) // iterate through it


             if(adjacent_find(in.begin(), in.end()) == in.end()) // don't print duplicates


             cout << *it<<endl; // and print out each string in the vector
}
```

Comment: Sure you don't want something that doesn't store dupes in the first place? If you don't, you can use `std::unique_copy` to copy them to output.

Comment: Following up on chris' answer, like a [`std::set<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the STL algorithms `std::unique()` or `std::unique_copy()`. They work with any STL container, not just vectors.

A simple example to print the vector to the standard output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v = { "hello", "hello", "world" };
    unique_copy(begin(v), end(v), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
}
```

If you want to perform this operation in-place instead, you can use `std::unique()`. It is important to keep in mind that this function does not physically remove the redundant elements, but it returns the iterator to the new logical end of the collection:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v = { "hello", "hello", "world" };
    auto newEnd = unique(begin(v), end(v));
    for_each(begin(v), newEnd, [] (string const& s) { cout << s << " "; });
}
```

Comment: If you're making the vector unique in place, I'd go for using the erase-remove idiom over storing my own end position.

Comment: @chris: I guess making generalized statements is risky here, it depends what kind of processing you have to do after. But yeah, common-sense says you more likely want to call `erase()`

Comment: Yes, I presumed it would be used a bit more afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Try `std::unique`, which removes all but the first element from every consecutive group of identical elements (more examples + information [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/unique.html)). Since your vector is sorted, this sounds like what you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

If your vector is already sorted, you can use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) to remove consecutive duplicates.

Another alternative is to construct an [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) from the vector. That will have unique elements by design.