# Cannot output vector<string> to a file

Tags: c++, vector, cout

I am new to C++. I am having trouble outputting data to a file. I am using an iterator to print out a map. The print method takes i, a key value, and prints out it's corresponding vector. Now, this works perfectly fine when I output normally using cout<< but when I try to put the same output into a file, my program crashes. I know it is the *it that in the outfile<< line that is crashing it, because if I replace it with some random string it outputs it to the file fine. Also, I know the parameters in the print method are not causing any problems, because I can transfer that method directly to the main function of the program and get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to fix this, thank you!
Here is my print method where the error is happening:

```
    public: void print(int i, vector<string> in, ostream& outfile) // print method for printing a vector and it's key
{

    sort(in.begin(), in.end()); // sort the vector alphabetically first

    vector<string>::iterator it; 

    it= unique(in.begin(), in.end()); // makes sure there are no duplicate strings

    in.resize( distance(in.begin(),it) );

    for( it = in.begin(); it != in.end(); it++ ) // iterate through it

    cout << i << ": "<< *it<<endl; // and print out the key value and each string in the vector
   // outfile<< i << ":" << *it<< endl; // prints to file
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but you could save yourself a bit of sorting and resizing by just creating an ``std::set`` from the ``std::vector``: ``std::set<string> s(in.begin(), in.end());``.

Comment: Between this question, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552633/c-how-to-detect-duplicates-in-vectorstring-and-print-one-copy) is there any part of your homework to take a vector of values and write out a list of unique values that is *not* being done for you on SO ? Credit where due, though, at least you wrote some code, which is more than most try.

Comment: @WhozCraig - credit where it's due, he tried and ran into a problem he didn't know about. With some of the teaching these days, I'm not surprised some people don't know about scoping properly.

Comment: @slugonamission And I concur. Honestly I'm impressed with his instructor for allowing him to use the tools of the std lib. He's got that going for him, which is nice to see for a change as well.

Comment: @user2016393: is the `cout << i ...` line meant to *replace* the `outfile << i ...` line just for debugging purposes, or are you actually trying to do both things? I mean writing both to the standard output and to the file?

Comment: @WhozCraig our instructor has not taught us c++ whatsoever, we were instructed to learn it ourselves.

Comment: @user2016393 well you're diving into the actual standard library, so thats a pretty good start. Any C++ *language* book can help you with the language basics, and you should definitely spend time on them. But using the library as the *amazing* tool it is can reap wonders in the long run. An incredible amount of time, honing, and optimizations has gone into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `cout` line at the same time? If so, I think I know what it is.

The `for` loop, without braces will execute the next statement as its loop body. If you use both the `cout` line and the `outfile` line, you will print everything, then after the loop, `it` will be located just past the end of the array. You then try and dereference this and write it to a file, which of course fails since you're dereferencing an invalid iterator.

Short answer, wrap the statements in your for loop with braces.

For example, you have the following (when indented properly):

```
for( it = in.begin(); it != in.end(); it++ ) // iterate through it
    cout << i << ": "<< *it<<endl; 
outfile<< i << ":" << *it<< endl; // prints to file
```

On the last line of that, `it = in.end()`, where `in.end()` is the element *just past* the end of the vector. You then try and access the element at that location which doesn't exist (and is invalid), and hence it fails. Instead, you need to move that inside the loop, which should read

```
for( it = in.begin(); it != in.end(); it++ ) // iterate through it
{
    cout << i << ": "<< *it<<endl; // and print out the key value and each string in the vector
    outfile<< i << ":" << *it<< endl; // prints to file
}
```

Comment: +1, nice catch. I spaced on the end-comment myself, not seeing the braces increased that reflex (at least for me).

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel silly that I didn't see that error prior. Originally I had only one statement in there, so when I added the second I just forget to bother with the braces I guess.

Comment: @user2016393 it is a *very* common mistake; one that some feel to rectify by being religious about using `{` and `}` even with a single statement. Don't feel bad at all; seasoned engineers aren't immune to this little trifle.

Answer (score 2):

@slugonamission already gave you the correct answer, so I'm just going to point out that your function can actually be simplified and made less error-prone. I am writing this as an answer just because code formatting is required, otherwise I would post it in a comment:

```
void print(int i, vector<string> v, ostream& o)
{
    sort(begin(v), end(v));
    v.erase(unique(begin(v), end(v))); // Do this in one step, no iterator mess
    for (auto const& s : v) // Avoid manual iteration cycles if you can
    {
        o << i << ":" << s << endl;
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @juanchopanza correctly points out, an even quicker way to achieve the same would be to transfer the vector's content into an associative container to ensure uniqueness. This would allow you to pass the vector by `const &`:

```
void print(int i, vector<string> const& v, ostream& o)
{
    unordered_set<string> c(begin(v), end(v));
    for (auto const& s : c)
    {
        o << i << ":" << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be further simplified by constructing an ``std::set`` from the input ``std::vector``.

Comment: @juanchopanza: As long as the main workload does not consist in iterating through all the elements of a collection, performing position-based access, or modifying the values in the collection (which is not possible with an associative container) then you're right, you can use `std::set` and avoid sorting every time you do the output. Let me add that.

Comment: Avoiding ``sort`` and ``unique`` would mean that ``v`` could be passed as ``const&``. I realise these details might be getting too refined for the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza: well, my answer was not strictly addressing the question anyway, because @slugonamission already spotted the mistake. I just wanted to suggest an alternative, less error-prone solution ("the less you do, the less you f**k up"). So adding some short comments doesn't hurt I believe. And yes, you could pass by `const&`, although that would mean your collection cannot have duplicates, which may be a undesirable restriction outside of that function.

Comment: I realise you addressed the important points, and I upvoted your answer. What I mean about the ``set`` and the ``const&`` is that the function can take a ``const vector<string>&`` with arbitrary ordering and duplicates, make a ``set`` from that instead of sorting, uniqueing, resizing... so the function signature remains the same. It is just an implementation detail.

Comment: @juanchopanza: oh, I see your point now. I guess, yes, that makes sense :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: edited again. I've used `unordered_set`, because insertions have O(1) complexity, while `set` has O(log n) complexity.

Comment: @Andy Prowl Thank you! I will try this out to simplify my code!